# DateTimePicker shows a dot as second value in the hour, minute and second field

Tags: sapui5

We are using the DateTimePicker control in version 1.102.2. When we select an hour, a minute or a second, we get in the corresponding fields as the second value only a dot.
Example: 1. 3. 5. instead of 12 31 50. This is only a display problem. If getting the value, it is ok.

Comment: I don't see a question. If it's a bug then create an incident: https://github.com/SAP/openui5/issues

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the issue is reported on GitHub at https://github.com/SAP/openui5/issues/3551 and being processed accordingly.